# Generalized Laplace--Beltrami operators

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a smooth surface $M$, we have the well-known Laplace--Beltrami operator which in coordinate-free form is given by $\mathrm{div}_M\,(\mathrm{grad}_M)$. However, we can also consider the more generalized form $\mathrm{div}_M\,(D\,\mathrm{grad}_M)$, where $D$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix acting on tangent vectors. In fact, this operator appears in many diffusion processes (see e.g., [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion)). Unfortunately, while this form is discussed in the PDE literature, I couldn't find any mathematical treatment of this operator in the differential (Riemannian) geometry community. Does someone know of a textbook about this particular object?

As a remark, I am aware of the [$p$-Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Laplacian). However, I am interested in the case when $D$ is a general SPD matrix.

Comment: It is not clear what that $D$ is. I suppose that your surface has to be in $\mathbb R^3$ in order that $D$ is defined (treat of $grad f$ as an vector in $\mathbb R^3$. But then $div_M$ is not so well defined.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question so that all of the operators are intrinsic. Does it make sense now?

Comment: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~lsc/uniformly-jdg.pdf (Is that what you are looking for?)

Comment: Thank you @John. Indeed, it seems relevant and for sure will serve (at least) as a starting point.

Comment: If the answer below is correct, which means that all operator of the form you wrote all given by $L_D$, and is called a drift Laplacian. Quite a lot of studies can been done on this operator (quite recently)

Answer (score 4):

To some extent you can think of $D$ as changing the metric with which you are calculating the Laplace-Beltrami operator, which is intuitive if you think of the effect of $D$ on diffusion or heat flow. 
In fact you can always pick a new metric $\tilde g$ on the surface so that your operator is of the form
$$L_D = \nabla_{\tilde g} \cdot e^{s(q)} \nabla_{\tilde g}$$
for a scalar function $s: M\to \mathbb{R}$, with $s$ and $\tilde g$ unique up to shifting $s$ by a constant. I wrote down a calculation for this a bit ago at
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2b01gm5pjhsnhh/smoothL.pdf?dl=0.

As an operator $L_D$ has more or less all of the properties of the ordinary Laplacian: it is elliptic, self-adjoint, obeys the maximum principle, vanishes on constants, has a discrete negative spectrum, etc. It does differ from the usual $L$ in that applying it to the embedding function no longer gives the mean curvature normal (i.e. for $M$ flat, $L_Df$ no longer vanishes when $f$ is linear).

If you do find references that discuss $L_D$ I'd also be interested in reading about them.

EDIT: The comments correctly point out that my calculation in the PDF is specific to two dimensions. But the above decomposition still holds in arbitrary dimension $n$, with
\begin{align*}
\tilde{g}(v,w) &= (\det D)^{1/n} g(v, D^{-1}w)\\
s &= \frac{1}{n} \log \det D.
\end{align*}

Comment: Um.... quite interesting. From the proof it seems that it works only for dimension $=2$. Did you try to generalize that? Also, that $L_D$ is in general called a drift Laplacian, in case anyone are interested.

Comment: @John Yes I think it work in any dimension (I was interested in this for a project involving elastic membranes so was focused mostly on the $n=2$ case).

Comment: One more question: In your note, is $g_1(X, Y) = g(M^{-1}X, M^{-1} Y)$? (Up to a positive constant)?

Comment: No it would be $\sqrt{\det M} g(X, M^{-1}Y)$.

Comment: @John I've worked out the correct formulas for arbitrary dimension and edited them into my post.

Comment: @user7530 if it is still relevant, I find these [notes](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/lecture-1-diffusion-operators/) to be extremely relevant and helpful.